# 'CIImage is undeclared type' strange error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Please, help to understand what's wrong here. I've tried both Xcode 6.0.1 and Xcode 6.1 beta 2. I have a simple extension.

```
extension UIImage {
    func saturate (toLevel level : Float) -> UIImage {
        // create filter
        let saturationFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
        saturationFilter.setValue(self.CIImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        saturationFilter.setValue(NSNumber.numberWithFloat(level), forKey: "inputSaturation")

        // create context
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)

        // render image with filter
ERROR:  let renderedImage = saturationFilter.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as CIImage
        let imageRef = context.createCGImage(renderedImage, fromRect: renderedImage.extent())

        return UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)
    }
}
```

But the compiler says "Use of undeclared type 'CIImage'". What the hell? I've tried to import CoreImage, but nothing changed

Comment: Seeing the same issue with both CGImage and CIImage. Happens in Xcode 6.2 beta but not Xcode 6.1. Only in UIImage extensions. Elsewhere builds fine. Any chance you could include the link to the radar?

Comment: Still an issue in Xcode 7.1.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `CoreImage.CIImage` instead of `CIImage` to disambiguate.

Answer (score 17):

In order to avoid the bug you can define a type alias.

```
typealias MYImage = CIImage
```

Then declare the input CIImage in your category as:

```
let inputImage = MYImage(image: self)
```

Comment: There goes an hour of my life. Thanks.

Comment: Or `typealias CIImage = CoreImage.CIImage` inside the method that requires `CIImage`.

Answer (score 7):

Seems to be bug in Xcode ,typecasting Fails only inside the extension block, You can directly access the output image using the property 'outputImage' which is of CIImage type. No need to use valueForKey, Try below code

```
 extension UIImage {
        func saturate (toLevel level : Float) -> UIImage {
            // create filter
            let saturationFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorControls")
            saturationFilter.setValue(self.CIImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            saturationFilter.setValue(NSNumber.numberWithFloat(level), forKey: "inputSaturation")

            // create context
            let context = CIContext(options: nil)

            // render image with filter
        let renderedImage = saturationFilter.outputImage
         let imageRef = context.createCGImage(renderedImage, fromRect: renderedImage.extent())

            return UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)
        }
    }
```

**************************** Update ***************************

I think In your case `ciImage` property of `UIImage` instance is `nil` , that's why its crashing. Note that `UIImage` is not in fact a `CIImage`. In other words, `UIImage`'s `CIImage` is not nil only if the `UIImage` is backed by a `CIImage` already (e.g. because it was generated by imageWithCIImage:). You can't use this to magically turn the `UIImage` into a `CIImage`, as you seem to be hoping to do.

So you need to initialise image with a CIImage instance, Try like this to get rid of crash

```
    let image = UIImage(named: "test")

    let ciImage = CIImage(image: image)

    let imageWithCIImage = UIImage(CIImage: ciImage)

    imageWithCIImage.saturate(toLevel: 0.5)
```

Comment: I've tried, but I always get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on the let renderedImage = saturationFilter.outputImage line

Comment: @VitaliyVashchenko seems ciImage is nil , Try updated answer.

Comment: So, there's no way yet to run this code. Because to create CCImage I have to use this class name. But that produces the above error too.

Comment: @VitaliyVashchenko use CIImage(image: image) outside the extension.

Comment: Yes, I did. Thanks. I mean it's not a good code. Filed a bug report to Apple, so they fix this ugly bug.

Comment: @VitaliyVashchenko Yes, its just a workaround , lets hope this issue be resolved in next release :)